# Kubernetes understanding output of - kubectl auth can-i

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I'm trying to understand why on one cluster an operation is permitted but on the other i'm getting the following

```
Exception encountered setting up namespace watch from Kubernetes API v1 endpoint https://10.100.0.1:443/api: namespaces is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default\" cannot list resource \"namespaces\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope ({\"kind\":\"Status\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"metadata\":{},\"status\":\"Failure\",\"message\":\"namespaces is forbidden: User \\\"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default\\\" cannot list resource \\\"namespaces\\\" in API group \\\"\\\" at the cluster scope\",\"reason\":\"Forbidden\",\"details\":{\"kind\":\"namespaces\"},\"code\":403}\n)"
```

I'm managing two Kubernetes clusters -

`clusterA` booted with Kops version `v1.14.8`

`clusterB` booted on AWS EKS version `v1.14.9-eks-f459c0`

So i've tried using the `kubectl auth` command to try figuring out and I do see that on one i'm allowed however on the second i'm not as you can see:

```
kubectl config use-context clusterA
Switched to context "clusterA".
kubectl auth can-i list pods --as=system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default -n kube-system
yes
kubectl config use-context clusterB
Switched to context "clusterB".
kubectl auth can-i list pods --as=system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default -n kube-system
no
```

Is there a way to understand what are these two decisions based on `yes/no`?
Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 4):

The decision `yes/no` is based on whether there is a `clusterrole` and a `clusterrolebinding` or `rolebinding` which permits the `default` serviceaccount in `kube-system` namespace  to perform verb `list` on resource `namespace`.

The trick in case of `namespace` resource is that there needs to be a `clusterrole` instead of `role` because `namespace` is a cluster scoped resource.

You check what are the `clusterrole`,`role`, `clusterrolebinding`,`rolebinding` exists in a kubernetes cluster using below command

```
kubectl get clusterrole,clusterrolebinding
kubectl get role,rolebinding -n namespacename
```

For more details refer Kubernetes RBAC [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)